# How to bind multiple stores to LoadMask

Tags: extjs

**ExtJS 4.1**

I can bind LoadMask to store with `store: Store` load mask config object property or with `bindStore()` load mask method.

But how to bind that mask to one more store(s) so mask toactivates on multiple stores loading?

Comment: You could try something like this: `var mask = { xtype: 'loadmask' ...};` then in your view: `masked: mask`

Comment: can't find `masked` property at all. What class is it belongs to?

Comment: Im pretty sure it's a property in alot of viewlike things: list, carousel etc... But looks like you already solved your question

Comment: Yes I did, thanks for the response anyway!

Comment: Don't put the answer in the question, answer the question in the space reserved for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bindStore()` method actually ADDS new store to list of stores served by `Ext.LoadMask`

Comment: Myabe it was changed since this asnwer being posted, but now `bindStore()` changes load mask store (ExtJS 4.2.1 here).